# Spotify getsavedtracks method?

Tags: spotify

I'm using Spotify iOS SDK beta 6 and trying to get a list of the tracks i've saved.

There is a getSavedTracks method that I'm trying to call:

[self getSavedTracks:(SPTSavedTrack *__autoreleasing *) range:(NSRange)]

And the same method I'm trying to implement:

-(void)getSavedTracks:(object-type **)buffer range:(NSRange)inRange

Right now, I'm at a lost as to what to put in the parameters.  I'm thinking this for the implementation?

-(void)getSavedTracks:(SPTSavedTrack **)buffer range:(NSRange)inRange {
    [SPTRequest savedTracksForUserInSession:self.session callback:^(NSError *error, SPTSavedTrack* trackObjects) {

```
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"*** Enabling playback got error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    self.savedTracks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:trackObjects, nil];
}];
```

}

There's nothing in their SDK API reference that mention this method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The methods you're talking about don't exist in the SDK.

You need `SPTRequest`'s `+savedTracksForUserInSession:callback:` method. Like this:

```
[SPTRequest savedTracksForUserInSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
    // Object contains the `SPTListPage` containing the first page of saved tracks
}];
```